# How to catch coroutine StopIteration exception?

Tags: python, coroutine

I use python2.7.

```
def printtext():
    try:
        line = yield
        print line
    except StopIteration:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = printtext()
    p.send(None)
    p.send('Hello, World')
```

I try to catch `StopIteration` exception but it is still raised without being caught.

Could you please give me some hint why the `StopIteration` exception escaped in this case?

Comment: It’s raised by `send`, not `yield`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got the point. @Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding when `StopIteration` is raised.  `StopIteration` is raised when a generator function exits, not during a `yield` expression.  As such, the only way to catch this is to do it outside the function...

```
def printtext():
    line = yield
    print line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = printtext()
    p.send(None)
    try:
        p.send('Hello, World')
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```